# A (preferably Java) library to execute cron jobs on an alternative time scale?

Tags: java, cron, simulation

I'm developing a simulation engine that needs to execute tasks according to a cron schedule. It's primary use case would be to generate large batches of simulated data to populate a database in a "realistic" fashion (high use during peak hours of the day, low activity on certain days [e.g. weekends] etc). However, nobody has time to wait several years to generate several years of data - so we need a way to scale the time so that generating a massive batch of data only takes a fraction of the time.

Does anyone know of a library that already supports this? Preferably a JVM-language library, though, it is not a hard requirement. I am familiar with Quartz, but I do not believe it provides any mechanism to "speed-up" cron execution or scale its calendar down.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear

Comment: @unludo - basically I need to compress a calendar down. such that a year is less than 1:1 with the concept of "year" as we exist in. If I were to schedule a cron job to execute once a year; for example, "30 1 1 jan *" I need that to really execute every 30 seconds because the duration of a year has been scaled down to mean 30 seconds of time elapsed rather than 31,622,400 seconds (standard year)

Does that help you understand a bit better what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [JiST](http://jist.ece.cornell.edu/)? Sounds like what you want:

> JiST is a high-performance discrete event simulation engine that runs
>   over a standard Java virtual machine. It is a prototype of a new
>   general-purpose approach to building discrete event simulators, called
>   virtual machine-based simulation, that unifies the traditional systems
>   and language-based simulator designs.

There is also a [list of discrete event simulators on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_discrete_event_simulation_software). If not JiST then one of these might be what you are looking for. Either way you'll have better luck if you search for the term [Discrete event simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation).

Comment: From the homepage: JiST User Guide. September 2003, updated March 2004.
I would not prefer something that old!